# Finding the best way to show html text in RichTextBlock

Tags: c#, html, richtextblock

I have some string like "Some **tmp** string with ***text*** " or "Some ***tmp*** string with **text**" or with other Html format.

**The Requirement** is to show this text with the same format in RichTextBlock.

**To do this**, I tried to make some thing like this:

```
   <RichTextBlock x:Name="rtb">
            <Paragraph x:Name="par">
                <Run FontStyle="Italic"
                     FontWeight="Bold">
                    Some tmp text
                </Run>
            </Paragraph>            
        </RichTextBlock>
```

But it formats all the text in Run element, but not the : "***Some tmp string with text*** "

I tried to make Run elements programmatically and add them to paragraph, but have the same problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at this Nuget Package: https://github.com/VincentH-Net/WinRT-RichTextBlock.Html2Xaml

Comment: thanks, now i am reading about it

Comment: ok let me know if you need additional help.

Comment: Sorry, but how correct implement it to project (i work with UWP):

1. I copied files to the folder(Common)
2. Implement in namespace in my MainPage

    xmlns:common="using:WinRT_RichTextBlock.Html2Xaml.Common">

3.But when use 

            <RichTextBlock x:Name="rtb" 
                           common:Properties.Html="{}">

            </RichTextBlock>

 It go to mistake, that there is no any Properties.Html

Comment: now all ok, entredString - some string like "Some tmp <b>string</b>"

            <RichTextBlock x:Name="rtb"
                           common:Properties.Html="{Binding entredString}">
            </RichTextBlock>

but HtmlChanged doesnt work

Comment: all work, but  **stream** null

Comment: // Read XSLT. In design mode we cannot access the xslt from the file system (with Build Action = Content), 
                // so we use it as an embedded resource instead:
                Assembly assembly = typeof(Properties).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
                using (Stream **stream** = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("WinRT_RichTextBlock.Html2Xaml.RichTextBlockHtml2Xaml.xslt"))
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

Comment: that always call exception

Comment: It's because the resources has a different name since it's in your assembly and with a different namespace. Call Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames () to see a list of the embedded resources and pass the right name when calling: ssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(**"PutYourResourceNameHere"**)

Comment: thanks, now will try

Comment: I make RichTextBlock Html2Haml.xslt like **embedded resource** , and changed ssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("PutYourResourceNameHere"), all work - thank you.
But it just split my input text by html tegs, with out formating text by html tags

Comment: I will try more, thank you for help